# List values in prolog

Tags: prolog

There are the following variables:

```
colour(blue).
colour(red).
colour(green).

size(small).
size(medium).
size(large).

price(10).
price(25).
price(40).
```

I want to make a list that will return every possible compination. Something like:

```
list=([colour(X),size(X),price(X)]).
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood correctly but you could try:

```
find_comb(L):- findall((X,Y,Z), (colour(X), size(Y), price(Z)) , L).
```

The above uses `findall/3` predicate to collect all possible combinations and store it in L.

Example:

```
    ?- find_comb(L).
    L = [ (blue, small, 10), (blue, small, 25), (blue, small, 40), (blue, 
    medium, 10), (blue, medium, 25), (blue, medium, 40), (blue, large, 10), 
    (blue, ..., ...), (..., ...)|...].
```

Based to your comment, to see full answer without '...' you could add:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,
                   [ quoted(true),
                     portray(true),
                     spacing(next_argument)
                   ]).
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. But why I get the dots at the end "(...,...)" instead of all the results?

Comment: I edited the answer to handle the '...' and give full answer take a look...

Comment: @NikosKiriakakis see, [Help, I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html)